# ios 10 push notification media attachment randomly does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an ios 10 app that has a Notification Service Extension that displays an image as part of the notification/alert (before it's opened).

My users are occasionally getting messages with no images attached. Later on in the day, I'll resend the exact notification and the image appears. I am having random, intermittent issues.

Is this a problem on my end or apple's end? Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. Someone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problem.  I found that image size is the one that matter for notification. When my image size was 626 X 626 media was not attached, so made size 320 X 320 it worked for attachment and getting crop in launch image. When I made 200 X 200. Attachment disappear once again.

Tried to find any apple guide line on internet but didn't get one. Came across you question while research and so hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

Internet consensus seems to be that you need to use as little memory as possible in these extensions. If you use too much, your violate the sandbox's memory constraint and get unloaded.

I rewrote my extension in ObjC rather than Swift. This helped.

Also do the download with a `downloadTask` rather than a `dataTask`. This way you are not using memory to download the images, URLSession (I believe) uses a system service our of process to do it.